# How do people build a friend presence system? (not a global user presence system)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There are several articles ([firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) and [firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence)) explaining how to build a user presence system but I cannot find a resource for a friend presence system.

A simple user presence system is not perfect for some applications such as chat apps where there are millions of users and each user wants to listen to only his/her friends. I've found similar questions:

- [exact same question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798427/efficient-and-scalable-social-presence-with-firebase-realtime-database)
- [exact same issue on github](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/discussions/4191)

Two ok solutions with a realtime database are: ([solutions are from the above stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798427/efficient-and-scalable-social-presence-with-firebase-realtime-database))

- Use many listeners (one for each friend) with a collection of users. Possibly have a cap on the number of friends to keep track of.
- Each user has friends collections and whenever a user's status changes, his/her status changes wherever he/she shows up in some user's friends collection as well.

Is there a better way to do? What kind of databases do chat apps like discord, whatsapp and etc. use to build their friends presence system?

Comment: Are you assuming that the Realtime Database presence system won't work for millions of users where *each user wants to listen to only his/her friends*? That would be an incorrect assumption as it works very well for that use case. There is no issue adding a listener on a node with millions of users, and the presence system will automatically update that with a users online status even if they unintentionally d/c. Do you have a specific coding problem we can assist with as asking for opinions is off topic for SO. Can you more clearly define what's being asked?

Comment: I am not assuming that the realtime database won't be able to handle millions of users. What I am curious is how do people who build the friends presence system do to only listen to subset of users in the database. If a user have 1000 friends, should the user listen to 1000 friends with 1000 listeners? It doesn't sound right that a user should listen to a node with millions of users just to update his/her friends online status. Or is there a way to structure friends so that each node contains one user's all friends and their online status?

Comment: You would add a query to only listen to a users friends. Then only events from those users are delivered to the app and no others. That's the nature of firebase  - you an think of the query as an active 'filter' that ignores everyone else except those that fall within the queries parameters

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how I can get a user's friends in one query. Don't I need to query 1000 friends if a user has 1000 friends (in this case I assume I have one node with all users)?
If I structure my users in a way that 'userX/friends' returns all friends of userX, I can query userX's all friends in a single query. To sync the online status of a friend (userY) in the database, I should update all of userY's status across all 'user*/friends/userY' though (let's say userY also has 1000 friends). Are you saying I should do the latter? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You're users would generally be stored in a single node but there are a number of way to approach this. For example, suppose you add an observer to the entire users node. If a user comes online that node will be presented to your app. If, in a child node, it's a friend, then your app can take action. If it's not, then ignore it. Likewise, as you mentioned, you could add a listener to each friend node.

Answer (score 1):

I came to two approaches that might be worth looking into. Note, that I have not tested how it will scale longer term as I just pushed to prod. First step, write a users presence on their user document (will need firebase, cloud functions, and cloud firestore per https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).
Then take either approach:

1. Create an array field on your user documents (users> {userID}) called friends. Every time you add a friend add your id to this array, and vice versa. Then, on the client run a function like:
   `db.collection(users).where("friends", "array-contains", clientUserId).onSnapshot(...)`

   In doing so, all documents with friends field that contains the clientUserId will be listened to for real-time updates. For some reason, my team didn't approve of this design but it works. *If anyone can share their opinion as to why I'd appreciate it*

2. Create a friend sub-collection like so: `users>{userID}>friends`
   . When you add a friend, add a document to your friend sub-collection with the id equal to your friends userID. When a user logs on, run a get query for all documents in this collection. Get the doc IDs and store into an array (call it friendIDs). Now for the tricky part. It'd be ideal if you can read use the in operator for unlimited comparison values because you can just run an onSnapshot as so:

   `this.unSubscribeFriends = db.collection(users).where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", friendIDs).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {get presence data})`. Since this onSnapshot is attached to `this.unSubscribeFriends` you just need to call this once to detach the listener:

   ```
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unSubscribeFriends && this.unSubscribeFriends()
    }
   ```

   Because a given users friends can definetely increase into the hundreds I had to create a new array called `chunkedFriendsArray` consisting of a chunked version of friendIDs (chunked as in every 10 string IDs I splice into a new array to bypass the in operator 10 comparison values limit). Thus, I had to map `chunkedFriendsArray` and set an onSnapshot like the one above for every array of a max length of 10 inside `chunkedFriendsArray`. The problem with this is that the all the listeners are attached to the same const (or `this.unSubscribeFriends` in my case). I have to call `this.unSubscribeFriends` as many times as chunkedArrays exist in `chunkedFriendsArray`:

   ```
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.state.chunkedFriendsArray.forEach((doc) => {
          this.unSubscribeFriends && this.unSubscribeFriends()
        })
    }
   ```

It feels weird having many listeners attached to the same const (method this.unSubscribeFriends) and calling the same exact one to stop listening to them. I'm sure this will lead to bugs in my production code.

There are other decentralize approaches but the two I listed are my best attempts at avoiding having a bunch of decentralized presence data.